# Parallax Background with a moving non repeating sprite

Tags: android, andengine, parallax

I'm using AutoParallaxBackground (from the AndEngine example) to create a background (only 20% of screen height), that appears to be moving. It works, but now I would like to add a Sprite that also moves in X direction, but isn't repeating.
The sprite should be positioned behind the background.
How can I achieve this? 
I tried setting the Z index on sprites, but it isn't working, probably because the background is always the lowest.

Comment: first add this sprite to parallax layer and than add  your background to your parallax

Comment: Yes, that puts the sprite behind the front layer, but it's still repeating. If I position it in the middle of the screen, I get 3 sprites, not one.

Comment: if you dont want to repeat your sprite then add first Background sprite to your scene and then add parallax layer.If it is not giving you answer please post it.